# Cannot create or update file in cmd, Powershell, nor Vscode. But I can through Sublime, git bash and File Explorer

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, file-permissions

I'm on Windows 10.

When I tried to create a file using **Powershell**, I got the below error

(Note: same behavior happened in **cmd.exe** but **not Git Bash**)

```
PS C:\Users\John\Documents> New-Item hi.txt -type file
New-Item : Could not find file 'C:\Users\John\Documents\hi.txt'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item hi.txt -type file
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: 
  (C:\Users\John\Documents\hi.txt:String) [New-Item], 
  FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.
  NewItemCommand
```

I can create, open, and update files normally from File Explorer and Git Bash.

I've checked the permission level of the directory and I do have full control of the directory.

```
PS C:\Users\John> (get-acl .\Documents\).access


FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : JOHN-DEEPBOOK\JOHN
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : JOHN-DEEPBOOK\JOHN
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Tried running PowerShell as Administrator and the same occurred.

This isn't the only directory that has this problem. /Desktop and /Contacts also have the same problem. I thought there might be something special for these built-in directories, but /Downloads is working fine. And they all have the same permission levels.

Another interesting behavior I found is that, when I invoked Sublime from PowerShell, it ran into the same issue where it couldn't save file. But when I invoked it from start menu it worked fine.

I also tried editing in Vscode, and it crashes when I tried to save the file. It crashed both when I invoked from PowerShell and start menu.

It seems to be more of a Windows issue rather than PowerShell solely, as I had the same problem with cmd.exe and Vscode.

If you had any clue of why this is happening, any suggestion is appreciated!!

Comment: Have an explore of `$error` and look at `.exception` to see if you can get more info.

Comment: You could try to monitor this with Sysinternal's Process Monitor.

Comment: Check if your profile is in fact relocated elsewhere, or Documents library is also relocated. Most likely you have some troubles accessing the relocated storage.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled on the same issue, it seems that Controlled Folder Access will silently block pwsh.exe from writing into Documents or otherwise accessing it (silently as in: there won't be a typical "access denied" notification).

If you go into the Protection History pane of Controlled Folder Access you'll see the blocks accredited to pwsh.exe. Allow the behavior and powershell will work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments, however none worked.

I'll just answer this myself since I found a workaround. I relocated Documents library to a new folder Documents2 and it solved all the permission issue.

I attempted to relocate Documents2 back to Documents (after deleting and creating a new folder), but the permission problems reoccurred. Still not sure why this is happening, but I'll leave it for now.